# Laravel dusk, incorrect testing result

Tags: php, laravel, testing, laravel-dusk, browser-testing

I just discovered Laravel Dusk, and wrote first test, which had to check for text on the page, but Laravel Dusk doesn`t see my page.

Test:

```
namespace Tests\Browser;
use Tests\DuskTestCase;
use Laravel\Dusk\Browser;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;
class FirstTest extends DuskTestCase
{
    public function testExample()
    {
        $this->browse(function (Browser $browser) {
            $browser->visit('/')
                ->assertSee('Laravel');
        });
    }
}
```

And `$browser->visit('/')` check is successful, but `$browser->visit('/')
                ->assertSee('Laravel');` check was failed.

In directory `tests/Browser/Screenshots` I found screenshot that page, which contains `No input file specified`

a part of file `.env`:

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:lypVdWwGkDn/R5L5PQ8tOUgfzf2WTzCSZU6GndMPuNM=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://127.0.0.1
```

After added file `.env.dusk.local` which contains:

`APP_URL=http://127.0.0.1:9519`

(As specified in the `Laravel Dusk` manual , the port must match the one specified in `DuskTestCase.php`)

`tests/Browser/screenshots/failed-test-*` contains: `command:`

Error text:

```
Time: 2.58 seconds, Memory: 12.00MB

There was 1 failure:

1) Tests\Browser\FirstTest::testExample
Did not see expected text [Laravel] within element [body].
Failed asserting that false is true.
```

`/home/vagrant/code/homestead_test/vendor/laravel/dusk/src/Concerns/MakesAssertions.php:400`
`/home/vagrant/code/homestead_test/vendor/laravel/dusk/src/Concerns/MakesAssertions.php:371`
`/home/vagrant/code/homestead_test/tests/Browser/FirstTest.php:18`
`/home/vagrant/code/homestead_test/vendor/laravel/dusk/src/Concerns/ProvidesBrowser.php:67`
`/home/vagrant/code/homestead_test/tests/Browser/FirstTest.php:19`

`FAILURES!`
`Tests: 1, Assertions: 1, Failures: 1.`

Sorry for my English =)

**UPD:**

a part of `.env.dusk.local` after deleting port: (for Jonas Staudenmeir).

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:lypVdWwGkDn/R5L5PQ8tOUgfzf2WTzCSZU6GndMPuNM=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://127.0.0.1
```

Comment: It should be `APP_URL=http://127.0.0.1` in your `.env.dusk.local` file (without the port).

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir, no, it doesn`t work.

Comment: In what environment are you running Dusk? Are you using a virtual machine like Homestead?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir, Yes

Comment: Are you running Dusk on your host machine (e.g. Windows or Mac OS) or in Homestead (via SSH)?

Comment: I connect to virtual machine(Homestead) via SSH (Host on Windows)

Comment: Does the screenshot still show "No input file specified"?

Comment: Yes, still show.

Comment: But the website works in the browser?

Comment: Yes, now,  laravel starter page.

Comment: Please add your `.env.dusk.local` file to the question.

Comment: After deleting port from ‘APP_URL’, they are identical

Comment: Early .env.dusk.local did not exists, i created him.

Comment: Without .env.dusk.local , dusk showed the same error

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir, I added this part of the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I changed `.env.dusk.local` (was set virtual host domain), and it's working.

e.g. `APP_URL=http://homestead.test`

Special thanks to [@Jonas Staudenmeir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4848587/jonas-staudenmeir)

Answer (score 0):

If Test fails on laravel desk it given me a random page of phpmyadmin on screenshot page.It must give me the page on which its giving an error.Please see the page bellow.
[Click Here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tm8G9.png)

Comment: In question I wrote about that screenshot file.

Answer (score 0):

There is a few ways you can try:

1.make sure copy ".env"  rename ".env.dusk.local" and change APP_URL={http://localhost:8000} //you serve
2. run php artisan serve
3. run php artisan dusk
Time: 2.17 seconds, Memory: 18.00 MB

### OK (1 test, 1 assertion)

debug:
1.change DuskTestCase.php to see what website page you browse
 http://localhost:9515 , DesiredCapabilities::chrome()

2.add one line in your test file ExampleTest.php  pause(1000)

Comment: all code refer to here:  https://github.com/laravel/dusk/issues/488